# Mapping Many-To-Many-Relation on the same table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

i am using nhibernate 3.3.1 and fluent-nhibernate 1.3. I try to map the following entity with fluent:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Relations { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, my person is in relation with some other persons. So I modeled the DB-Table like the following:

```
    | Persons
----+----------------------
 PK | Id int
    | Name nvarchar(100)

    | Relations
----+----------------------
 PK | Id int
 FK | Person1Id int
 FK | Person2Id int
```

So I want a mapping, where the relations of the person is loaded, no matter if the actual person is referenced as Person1Id or Person2Id.

Is this possible with fluent? And if not, is it possible with a hbn.xml mapping file?

Thanks for help,
Koray

Comment: Did you already try HasManyToMany(x => x.Relations) in your PersonMap class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't map it *directly*. You need to create two properties:

```
public virtual IList<Person> Relations1 { get; set; }
public virtual IList<Person> Relations2 { get; set; }
```

And then create a projection property that merges them:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Person> Relations
{
    get { return Relations1.Concat(Relations2); }
}
```

(I'm assuming you know how to do the first part; let me know if you don't)

Comment: Will NHibernatw be able to check in both columns, for example if I want to load the Relations of Person with Id 2, because it can have its own Id either in column Person1Id or Person2Id?